# how to manage particular one user or session user upload total data upto 1gb like dropbox using php?

Tags: php, mysql

how to manage particular one user or session store user upload total data(like videos,music) upto 1gb like dropbox using php? 
means overall data upload 1 gb after show some of warning massage display

currently i code for uploding files like this
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

```
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
             $allowedImageTypes = array("audio/aac","audio/mp4","audio/mpeg","audio/mp3","audio/mpg","audio/mpeg","audio/ogg","audio/oga","audio/wav","audio/webm");
                if (!in_array($file_type, $allowedImageTypes)) 
                {
                     echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                       window.alert('Invalide file type')
                       window.location.href='music_upload.php';
                   </SCRIPT>");
                   exit;
                }
    if($file_size > 1000000000){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 1 GB';
    }       
    $query="INSERT INTO `cp_drive`.`music_collection` ( `FILE_NAME`, `FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`,`users_name`) VALUES ( '$file_name', '$file_size', '$file_type','$login_session')";


    $sel="select * from userregister where username='$login_session'";
    $a=mysqli_query($connection,$sel);
    $b=mysqli_fetch_array($a);
    $c=$b['unique_directory'];

    $desired_dir="$c/music";

    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
     mysqli_query($connection,$query);          
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    /*  echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       window.alert('upload successfully')
       window.location.href='music_upload.php';
   </SCRIPT>");  */ 
    echo "<div id=\"successmsg\">upload successfully </div>";
        //header('Location:index.php');
    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'music_upload.php';\",1800);</script>";
}
```

}

in this code validation check for file less than 1gb but how to manage user all uploding data max 1gb???

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then visit [GET started](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow), and finally, read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But keep in mind that *SO is a community that helps*, and **no one will do all the work for you**.

Comment: Please read also [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Answer (score 0):

add if condition like this before file upload code

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

        $sql1 = ("SELECT SUM(FILE_SIZE) FROM music_collection where users_name='$login_session'");
        $rs1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);
        $result1 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs1);



        $sql4 = ("SELECT SUM(FILE_SIZE) FROM compress_files where users_name='$login_session'");
        $rs4 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql4);
        $result4 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs4);

        $fin=$result[0]+$result2[0];  

            if($fin>$max_limit){  //check max upload limit

                echo "file size is"."$fin";
                echo "<div id=\"errormsg\">max limit reached..upload max 1GB data </div>";
                echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'video_upload.php';\",1800);</script>";
                exit;
            }
```